# How do I check for an object being Nothing in VB6?

Tags: vb6

In my VB6 application I have an array of objects declared thus...

```
Dim MyArray() as MyClass
```

This array is filled in as processing goes on

```
Set MyArray(element) = passed_object
```

and as elements are no longer wanted,

```
Set MyArray(otherelement) = Nothing
```

When using the array, I want to use a loop like

```
For i = 1 To Ubound(MyArray)
    If MyArray(i) <> Nothing Then    ' Doesn't compile
        ...do something...
    End If
Next i
```

But I can't get anything likely-looking to compile. I've also tried

```
If MyArray(i) Is Not Nothing Then
```

Should I want to do this, and if so, what test should I put in here?

Comment: VB has an `IsNot` operator, so just remove a space to get `If MyArray(i) IsNot Nothing Then`... there is usually a preference for this syntax over `Not... Is Nothing`

Comment: @u8it, VB6 does not have an IsNot operator. That appeared only in VB.Net.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
If Not MyArray(i) Is Nothing Then
```

Answer (score 15):

```
If Not MyArray(i) Is Nothing Then
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
IsNothing(<object here>)
```

this should work in VB6:

```
<object here> Is Nothing
```

Comment: add some explanations also

Comment: Yes, that's what all the other answers say. They've been here for over two years. Sorry, but your answer doesn't add anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Private Function IsNothing(objParm As Object) As Boolean
        IsNothing = IIf(objParm Is Nothing, True, False)
    End Function
```

Comment: Or a bit more succinctly, `IsNothing = objParam Is Nothing`.